# Youtube freezes video while changing audio volume on 18.04 with Xorg

Tags: xorg, 18.04, youtube

Youtube video freezes video while audio volume is changed using keyboard.

This happen only when I log in using Xorg. Never happened when using Wayland.

Apparently it is related to the volume animation since it never happens when changing volume using the mouse.

*My system is a fresh 18.04 install.*

*Actually, I updated from 16.04, broke a few things, fixed them, and stumbled upon this problem. Then I decided to make a fresh install and the same happened. I'm also quite sure it didn't happen on the live image.*